# Text formatting, indent

Tags: formatting, indentation, paragraphs, typewriter

How can I remove the indent after 'itemize'? I want 'algorithm 1...' to be written from the same place as header and first sentence.

Is there a better way than \qquad to format lines after 'Inputs:' and 'Outputs:' with indentation in the text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
 left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,%
 footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{algotabularx}
 {\tabularx{\linewidth-\inoutsize-\widthof{~~~}-4\tabcolsep-
\rightskip}[t]}
{\endtabularx} 


\begin{document}
\section{The Dijkstra’s algorithm}
The Dijkstra’s algorithm is used for finding shortest paths in a graph G = $\langle{V,E}\rangle$. The characteristics of the Dijkstra’s algorithm variant presented here are as follows:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Works on a \underline{weighted graph}.
    \item Only \underline{non-negative weights} are allowed.
    \item Calculates minimum distances from one node $v_0$ to all the others
    \item It has the complexity of $O(\left|V\right|^2)$.
\end{itemize}

Algorithm 1 presents a pseudocode for the Dijkstra’s algorithm.\\


\begin{algotabularx}{@{}p{3cm}p{0.5cm}p{10cm}X@{}} 

Inputs: \\
\qquad $G = \langle{V,E}\rangle$  & - & a weighted graph \\ 
\qquad $v_0$ & - & the initial node to determine distances from \\

Outputs: \\ 
\qquad $\forall v \in V : d(v)$ & - & a set of distances from $v0$ calculated for all nodes $v \in V$  \\
\qquad $\forall v \in V : d(p)$ & - & a set of predecessors on the shortest path from v0 \\

\end{algotabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just remove the blank line after `\end{itemize}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Insert `\noindent` to suppress indentation.

Answer (score 1):

The double line break after `\end{itemize}` indicates that you are starting a new paragraph, which causes the indentation. Remove one of the line breaks to indicate that it is part of the same paragraph:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,%
footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{algotabularx}
{\tabularx{\linewidth-\inoutsize-\widthof{~~~}-4\tabcolsep-
        \rightskip}[t]}
{\endtabularx} 


\begin{document}
    \section{The Dijkstra’s algorithm}
    The Dijkstra’s algorithm is used for finding shortest paths in a graph G = $\langle{V,E}\rangle$. The characteristics of the Dijkstra’s algorithm variant presented here are as follows:
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Works on a \underline{weighted graph}.
        \item Only \underline{non-negative weights} are allowed.
        \item Calculates minimum distances from one node $v_0$ to all the others
        \item It has the complexity of $O(\left|V\right|^2)$.
    \end{itemize}   
    Algorithm 1 presents a pseudocode for the Dijkstra’s algorithm.\\
    
    
    \begin{algotabularx}{@{}p{3cm}p{0.5cm}p{10cm}X@{}} 
        
        Inputs: \\
        \qquad $G = \langle{V,E}\rangle$  & - & a weighted graph \\ 
        \qquad $v_0$ & - & the initial node to determine distances from \\
        
        Outputs: \\ 
        \qquad $\forall v \in V : d(v)$ & - & a set of distances from $v0$ calculated for all nodes $v \in V$  \\
        \qquad $\forall v \in V : d(p)$ & - & a set of predecessors on the shortest path from v0 \\
        
    \end{algotabularx}
    
\end{document}
```

leads to:
[image]